# How can I quickly generate all permutations of a string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, math, permutation

I am currently using this function, and the code works exactly as it should.
`self.chars.permutation.map(&:join).uniq.group_by(&:chr)`

However, once the string is more than 10 characters, it takes a lot of time to generate all permutations. How could I generate permutations quicker?

Comment: I would argue that you can't. The longer the string the more permutations. More permutations need more time and memory to be generated. Why do you need to generate that permutation? The might be more efficient ways to solve your problem.

Comment: I am generating permutations to check if any anagrams of a string are in a dictionary

Comment: i think you will need a different algorithm

Comment: i think a best way is to use gems for parallel processing: https://github.com/grosser/parallel or https://github.com/bruceadams/pmap but it's all the same, because ruby have a gil, for some advantages use jruby, but be careful possible OutOfMemory

Comment: How big is the dictionary? It might be more cost efficient to cache a set of dictionary words whose letters are sorted alphabetically. If you do that you can check the sorted string against the set very quickly.

Comment: @mike: you are making the same mistake as the OP, you are vastly underestimating how fast n! grows. Even if you can generate a permutation for every single CPU cycle, and you have 100 cores, and those cores run at 5GHz, it still takes one million years to generate the permutations for a 25 character string. Parallelization is not the answer, a different algorithm is. Or, to put it differently: you are answering the OP's question literally ("how do I speed up generating permutations"), which is okay, but there really is no point: no matter how much you speed it up, n! will outgrow you.

Comment: Exactly. Throw n cores at the problem, you still have `(n-1)!` to go.

Comment: @JörgWMittag yep, your comment is correct, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than computing all permutations of each word, a better approach is to first create a hash from the dictionary, whose keys are strings sorted by character and whose values are arrays containing all words in the dictionary which are anagrams of the key. The arrays are empty when the word contains no anagrams in the dictionary (other than itself).

```
words      = %w| god act bat tar a lion stop |
  #=> ["god", "act", "bat", "tar", "a", "lion", "stop"]
dictionary = %w| cat dog a fowl bat god act lion pig donkey loin post pots
                 spot stop tops| 
  #=> ["cat", "dog", "a", "fowl", "bat", "god", "act", "lion", "pig",
  #    "donkey", "loin", "post", "pots", "spot", "stop", "tops"]

h = dictionary.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) do |w,h|
  h[w.each_char.sort.join] << w
end
  #=> {"act"=>["cat", "act"], "dgo"=>["dog", "god"], "a"=>["a"], "flow"=>["fowl"],
  #    "abt"=>["bat"], "ilno"=>["lion", "loin"], "gip"=>["pig"], "deknoy"=>["donkey"],
  #    "opst"=>["post", "pots", "spot", "stop", "tops"]}
```

We can then obtain all the anagrams of each word in `words` by sorting the word on its characters and seeing whether that is a key in the hash.

```
words.each_with_object({}) do |w,g|
  key = w.downcase.chars.sort.join
  values = h.key?(key) ? (h[key]-[w]) : []
  g[w] = values
end
  #=> {"god"=>["dog"], "act"=>["cat"], "bat"=>[], "tar"=>[], "a"=>[],
  #    "lion"=>["loin"], "stop"=>["post", "pots", "spot", "tops"]}
```

Comment: Nice. Once again, we have very similar solutions. You're basically on every question for which `each_with_object` can be used :)

Comment: @Eric, I've only learned 23 Ruby methods, and `each_with_object` happens to be one of those.

Comment: Carefully choosing those 23 methods, you could go a long way before needing anything else!

Answer (score 2):

> I am currently using this function, and the code works exactly as it should.
>   `self.chars.permutation.map(&:join).uniq.group_by(&:chr)`
>
> However, once the string is more than 10 characters, it takes a lot of time to generate all permutations. How could I generate permutations quicker?

You can't. Well, maybe there are ways of speeding it up a little, but there is really no point: the number of permutations is much too large. For just 25 characters, even if we assume that you can generate one permutation for every CPU cycle, even if we assume that you have a 5GHz CPU, even if we assume that your CPU has 100 cores, even if we assume that the work can be perfectly distributed among those cores, it will still take close to one *million years* to generate. There's just that many of them.

In short: there is no point in even trying to speed up your algorithm. You need to get away from generating permutations altogether.

Answer (score 2):

## Theory

No need for permutations :

- Sort the letters in your string
- Sort the letters in every word in the dictionary
- Look for same sorted letters
- Done!

## Implementation

```
class String
  def sorted_letters
    downcase.chars.sort.join
  end
end

class AnagramFinder
  @dict = '/usr/share/dict/american-english'
  class << self
    def get_anagrams(word)
      sorted_dict[word.sorted_letters]
    end

    def all
      sorted_dict.values.select { |anagrams| anagrams.size > 1 }
    end

    def sorted_dict
      @sorted_dict ||= generate_sorted_dict
    end

    private

    def generate_sorted_dict
      File.foreach(@dict).with_object(Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }) do |word, sorted_dict|
        word.chomp!
        sorted_dict[word.sorted_letters] << word
      end
    end
  end
end

p AnagramFinder.get_anagrams('impressiveness')
#=> ["impressiveness", "permissiveness"]
p AnagramFinder.get_anagrams('castor')
#=> ["Castor", "Castro", "Croats", "actors", "castor", "costar", "scrota"]
p AnagramFinder.all.last(5)
#=> [["wist", "wits"], ["withers", "writhes"], ["woodworm", "wormwood"], ["wriest", "writes"], ["wrist", "writs"]]
p AnagramFinder.all.max_by(&:length)
#=> ["Stael", "Tesla", "least", "slate", "stale", "steal", "tales", "teals"]
```

This example needed 0.5s on my slowish server, and most of it was spent building the sorted dictionary. Once it is done, the lookup is almost instantaneous.

`"impressiveness"` has 14 characters, you would need a **very** long time to generate all the permutations (14! = 87178291200).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [`lazy`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-lazy) might be an option. It doesn't need as much memory as generation all permutations before checking for a special condition.

Something like:

```
'my_string'.chars.permutation.lazy.map(&:join).each do |permutation|    
  puts permutation if dictionary.include?(permutation)
end
```

Comment: If `my_string #=> "aardvark"`, `lazy` would speed finding a permutation match, but unfortunately that match would probably be the word `"aardvark`" itself. Even if you skipped the permutation that is the word itself, there will still be a vast number of permutations to check for most longer words. Converting the dictionary to a set would of course help, but I don't think computing permutations, even lazily, is the way to go here.

Answer (score 1):

If we look at [Permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) we see the number of permutations of an eleven letter word with no letter repeated would be 39,916,800. However for MISSISSIPPI it is 11! / ( 1! * 4! * 4! * 2!) = 34,650. The first is going to take a long time however you do it, but if you can reduce the search space using repeating characters it might become more manageable. The standard permutation method does not remove repeats.

Searching for "ruby permutations without repetition" might turn up some algorithms.

Comment: You make a good point, but have only raised a possibility in your last sentence. If you are not suggesting a particular algorithm, this should be a comment, not an answer.